# GWT: Error in hosted mode after localization

Tags: java, gwt

I got some problems after making my gwt app "international".

my app.gwt.xml:

```
<module rename-to='app'>
    <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User' />
    <inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.I18N" />

    <!-- Inherit the default GWT style sheet. -->
    <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.standard.Standard' />
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.chrome.Chrome'/> -->
    <!-- <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.theme.dark.Dark'/> -->

    <!-- Specify the app entry point class. -->
    <entry-point class='dk.blabla.app.client.Entry' />

    <!-- Specify the paths for translatable code -->
    <source path='client' />
    <source path='shared' />

    <!-- Specify the locales you will be supporting -->
    <extend-property name="locale" values="da" />
</module>
```

And i added the folloing to app.html header

```
<meta name="gwt:property" content="locale=en">
```

Now I can not start my app in hosted mode. I get the following errors

> [ERROR] [app] - Deferred binding
>   failed for
>   'com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.CldrImpl';
>   expect subsequent failures
>
> [ERROR] [app] Unable to load module
>   entry point class
>   dk.blabla.app.client.App (see
>   associated exception for details)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred
>   binding failed for
>   'com.google.gwt.i18n.client.impl.CldrImpl'
>   (did you forget to inherit a required
>   module?)

Edit:

By the way I am using eclipse with the google plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should add

```
<inherits name="com.google.gwt.i18n.CldrLocales"/>
```

to your app.gwt.xml. 
For detailed information see [Runtime Locales](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nLocale.html#LocaleSpecifying)